# Count Distinct Date MySQL returning one row

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so be ready I'm working on a weird base :
Every table has 3 column only : varchar('Object'),varchar('Property'),varchar('Value')

Here is a fiddle I've build with examples of my tries
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de22eb/1

I need to extract the last time a server was update. But i'm not interested in the server itself it's more about the date. Once I know that there was an update for a date I'm looking to count every updates on that day.

To do so I'm using 2 tables : the server table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server` (
  `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(200) NOT NULL
);
```

And the event table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `event` (
  `name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(80) NOT NULL
);
```

Please go watch the fiddle to have an idea of the content.

I want to have a result like this (based on my example) :

```
Date         Number patched
2017-11-14   2
2017-11-04   1
```

The problem is that I don't know where I'm wrong on my query (I've separated the step for better understanding inside the fiddle) :

```
Select date_format(d.val, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date', COUNT(distinct 
date_format(d.val, '%Y-%m-%d')) as 'Number' 
FROM (
    Select b.serv,b.val 
    FROM (
        Select serv,val FROM (
          Select name as serv, value as val FROM event 
          where field='server_vers' and 
          value!='None' 
          order by serv ASC, 
          val DESC LIMIT 18446744073709551615) a 
        group by a.serv) b, 
        server c 
    where b.serv = c.name and c.field = 'OS' and c.value = 'Fedora'
) d group by date_format(d.val, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

It's giving me only one row. Adding `group by date_format(d.val, '%Y-%m-%d')` at the end makes the `Count` useless. How can I fix that ?

I want to have for each server for a given OS type the last patch date and then sum the result by date.

Comment: You added so much details to your question that I got lost in what you really need. It seems like just a simple join with a group by and count but you did not explain what to filter so you have those two rows as a result. Take a look at this query i made and, explain me, what should I use to filter it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de22eb/11

Comment: I want to have for each server the last patch date and then sum the result by date.

Comment: On a side note: Don't use date functions on strings. `DATE_FORMAT` is a function to convert a date to string. But what you store is a string already. If you want to manipulate strings, use string functions. In your case `LEFT` to get the left part of the string which represents the date part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you needed ?

```
SELECT dates.date, COUNT(dates.date) as patch_count
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(date_format(event.value, '%Y-%m-%d')) as date
  FROM event
  JOIN server ON (event.name = server.name)
  WHERE (server.field = 'OS' AND server.value = 'Fedora')
  GROUP BY event.name ) as dates
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Here's the fiddle :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de22eb/37/0

Explanation : We get the last date for every server name. That gives a list of last dates. Then we use this as a table, that we can group on to count each different value.

Comment: This is what I need I just need one thing more : being able to filter by OS type

Comment: Edited to filter by OS.

Answer (score 1):

The datetimes are stored as strings. The first ten characters of that string represent the date. So you get the date with `left(value, 10)`.

You get the last update per server by grouping by server and retrieving `max(left(value, 10))`, because alphabetic order works on `'yyyy-mm-dd'`.

```
select name, max(left(value, 10))
from event 
where field = 'server_vers' 
and value <> 'None' 
group by name
```

Build up on this to get the count of updates on those last-update dates:

```
select left(value, 10), count(*)
from event
where field = 'server_vers'
and left(value, 10) in
(
  select max(left(value, 10))
  from event 
  where field = 'server_vers' 
  and value <> 'None' 
  group by name
)
group by left(value, 10)
order by left(value, 10);
```

Comment: This is indeed what I need I've add one thing : I have to filter by OS type.

Comment: You'd add `and name in (select name from server where field = 'OS' and value = 'Fedora')`. However, you say that my query is what you need and Steve's query is what you need. But you do notice the difference? I'm counting all updates on last-update dates, while Steve counts all last updates on last-update dates.